# Export XML table value as CSV

Tags: html, xml, csv, xslt

i have an xml file consisting of various tags. I am interested in tag named **tbody** which is followed by **tr** and **td**. But i only want to parse data which appear in 3rd **tbody**. i have written this piece of code, but its not able to filter it on the basis of position[]

```
    <xsl:for-each select="//tbody[position()=3]">
        <xsl:for-each select="tr">
            <xsl:for-each select="td">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Can anyone please help me guide whts wrong with what i have done ? How can i perform loop on **tbody** with position as 3 in the xml file.

The xml by itself is very huge and generated by using the **view page source** option. You can download the same from below link https://ufile.io/4foqi

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample of your XML please? Thank you!

Comment: Note, 59Kb is not very huge (although too big to include in the question). However, you should really include a reduced sample in your question to make it easy to reproduce the issue. Also, external links may disappear over time (Indeed, the one you link to will self-destruct in 4 weeks in Mission Impossible style). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `//tbody[position()=3]` what you are actually doing is getting all `tbody` elements that are in that position under their own parent.

If you want the third `tbody` element no matter where it occurs in the XML, do this

```
<xsl:for-each select="(//tbody)[position()=3]">
```

Note, you can shorten the statement to this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="(//tbody)[3]">
```